# Behaviour of Neovim when in insert mode is different from expected

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, insert-mode

I recently switched from vim to neovim.

I have the following keybindings in neovim:

```
vim.keymap.set("i", "0", "<Esc>la", { noremap = true }) 
vim.keymap.set("i", "00", "0", { noremap = true })  
vim.keymap.set("i", "[]", "{}<Esc>ha", { noremap = true })
```

Now when I press `0[]` in quick succession, I expect the cursor to move one step forward and write `{}` with cursor inside the braces (this is how vim used to behave).

However, what I get is that the cursor moves one step forward and writes `[]` on the screen (instead of curly braces).

Can somebody see why this is the case?

Comment: I can reproduce the behavior but the first mapping is dangerous. If it used at the end of the line the `l` move will fail and the `a` will not be executed.

Comment: Thank you for the response? So is it indeed an unwanted behaviour or is it a feature of neovim? And you are right about the danger of the first mapping but I use it only for tex files and have used it for many years without problems. Can you make it better?

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```lua
vim.keymap.set("i", "0", "<C-o>l", { noremap = true })
vim.keymap.set("i", "00", "0", { noremap = true })
vim.keymap.set("i", "0[]", "<C-o>l{}<C-o>h", { noremap = true }) 
vim.keymap.set("i", "[]", "{}<C-o>h", { noremap = true })
```

Comment: I haven't tried this. But why do we need to separately map `0[]`? Shouldn't neovim automatically execute the mapping for `0` and the mapping for `[]` one after the other when we press `0[]`?

Comment: It seems that in Neovim the buffer waiting a disambiguation is pass as such to the mapping list. In your case `0[` do not match anything and is then output as such. If we add a mapping for `0[]` then the disambiguation is resolved with the full string and it solves your problem (not nice but working :-| )